# Whitelisting Databricks IP in External API

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Hi Am trying to do perform api request using Databricks python notebook and receiving error that the ip was not whitelisted. Can someone explain how to know which IP is used by Databricks to connect to API so that I can whitelist it.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.someapi.com'
myobj = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}

x = requests.post(url, json = myobj)

print(x.text)
```

Error: The IP you're trying to access is not whitelisted. Please whitelist using the following url

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to do `%sh curl https://ifconfig.me/` to get your outgoing IP, but it may not be stable.

Another approach is to route outgoing traffic via NAT Gateway that will have stable IP(s).  You can look through process in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview#custom-routes).